# How to run a detached application by terminal command in Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qprocess

I want to use commands:

```
cd /opencv/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/samples/cpp/
./cpp-example-facedetect lena.jpg
```

to run a sample code of OpenCV on clicked() method of button in Qt application. 
So I use:

```
void MainWindow::on_btSample_clicked()
{
        QProcess process1;
        QProcess process2;

        process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

        process1.start("cd /opencv/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/samples/cpp");
        process1.waitForBytesWritten();
        process2.start("./cpp-example-facedetect lena.jpg"); 
}
```

I added necessary library to use it. But I have an error when I run my application.

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("./cpp-example-facedetect") is still running.
```

How can I fix it? If the way I make isn't right, plz give me another way. Thank u in advance!

Comment: try with process2.waitForFinished();

Comment: @Marco i tried this but I got nothing, there is no error and no result in screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two issues here:

Firstly your `QProcess process2` is probably going out of scope before it finishes (i.e. gets destroyed since its out of scope). You either have to wait for it to finish (using `waitForFinished()`, or make it a pointer or member variable (to change the scope) and connect the `finished()` signal to some handling slot (which can do the tidy up).

The other thing here is, it looks like you just want to set the working directory, so I don't think piping the cd command into your executable is the way to go, it would be easier to do something like:

**EDIT**

I have edited my example to show you how to get the output:

```
QProcess myProc;

qDebug() << "Starting process\n";
// Setup the working directory
QDir::setCurrent("D:\\software\\qtTest");

// Start the process (uses new working dir)
myProc.start("test.bat");

myProc.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << myProc.readAll();
```

I knocked this up on my windows box in about 2 minutes and tested it for you... I could do it on linux but that will take me a little longer because I have to boot it up :o  ... but if you want I will.

**EDIT 2**

If you want to detach the process entirely:

```
QProcess myProc;

qDebug() << "Starting process\n";
// Setup the working directory
QDir::setCurrent("D:\\software\\qtTest");

// Start the process (uses new working dir)
myProc.startDetached("test.bat");
```

Now I am not 100% sure you can get the output back from the process... it is now nothing to do with your Qt app...

Comment: i tried this but I got nothing, there is no error and no result in screen. Have u another way to make it run? Thank u

Comment: I have edited my example... I think it is working for you, but you don't see anything maybe because you are not retrieving the output?... so use waitForFinished() and then read the output using `readAll()`. IF this is a long process then you probably need to set it up differently and wait for the readReady() signal and read output as it comes in ... again using slot/signal. If you need that example will take longer to write it.

Comment: thank u very much. the sample code run as a widget application, it'll show an image, but I don't know the retrieving  is necessary in my case. What I need is just run it and don't care its result :D.

Comment: oh, but currently my app don't show anything when I click the button :(. It's not the thing I expect :(

Comment: Oh sorry... what do you mean? What do you want it to show? I am not 100% clear. The code I wrote will only send the text to debug... not to the GUI

Comment: what I mean is I need run the sample application seperately. It doesn't associate my application. and, additional info about sample application is: ".exe" in the end of its name. I don't know if it's particular case? sorry for my poor english :D. my explaination is so bad :D

Comment: hmm... I `think` I understand what you mean... take a look at `startDetached()`, this will start the application in a new process, but it will detatch it from your application. So... if you close your Qt app `cpp-example-facedetect` will keep running... let me try to re-jig my example again.

Comment: oh, definitely. Bother u again, so sorry my friend :D

Comment: So.... I added the example, its actually simpler. When I run this, now I see that a separate command prompt starts (in your case some other GUI?) and I close my Qt app and its still running. My bat file is just pinging www.google.com continuously :o

Comment: I found my problem. Thank u very much :)

Comment: Cool : ) ... remember if it was something different to what is in my answer you should clarify it so that the next person can read about it : )