# How to execute a detached C++ executable file from another Qt program?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to execute an .exe file, which was compiled by g++ (or gcc) from a Qt program. I refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593993/how-to-run-a-detached-application-by-terminal-command-in-qt-application) and try to make it run:

```
// Setup the working directory
QDir::setCurrent("/home/myproject");

// Start the process (uses new working dir)
bool t= myProc.startDetached("./work");
if (t==false) std::cout<< "Error";
else std::cout <<"OK";
```

but the result I have is always "Error" and there is no change in my screen even if the program "work" is a GUI program. I did it in terminal but in QProcess I can't :(. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about adding a `.exe` to your executable?

Comment: @AlexisP. I don't see ".exe" in example so I don't add it

Comment: You have inverted logic there: t is false when there’s an error, not true. Try with an absolute path instead of `./work`. The current directory looks broken, it should be an absolute path also, e.g. `/home/youruser`. Also note that startDetached is a static method and does nothing to `myProc`, `QProcess::startDetached(…)` would be the usual syntax (but yours should work, too)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld sorry, my mistake. I fixed that. The program worked in terminal but in QProcess it can't run :(

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a typo issue. Make sure `QDir::setCurrent("home/")` does return true; if not, directory change failed and you are not in the directory you expect.
Try starting your executbale attached first (use `myProc.execute()` instead of `myProc.startDetached()`, and check what happens. This may reveal some errors that you cannot see when started detached. Make sure your program 'work' does not perform any input from stdin.

Comment: it's not my problem. I think it's about QProcess :(

Comment: @Nguyễn Chí: please, give some more inputs... difficult to understand what's happening with the fex info you provided.

Comment: it's a GUI program, is a sample code of OpenCV library in C++.